# Sorting html elements that were ordered by roman numeral IDs

Tags: javascript, html, roman-numerals

I have generated HTML (i have no control of this) similar to this:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li id="I">one</li>
  <li id="II">two</li>
  <li id="III">three</li>
  <li id="IV">four</li>
  <li id="IX">nine</li>
  <li id="V">five</li>
  <li id="VI">six</li>
  <li id="VII">seven</li>
   .....
   ......
   ......
</ul>
```

Basically, the code **(SQL -> XML -> XSLT)** that generated this is sorting by a field (which represents a roman numeral field)  alphabetically. Is there a way i can use javascript to reorder the list items from the clientside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>Small Page</title>
<script>
function sortRomanIds(){
    fromRoman= function(s){
        s= s.toUpperCase();
        var L= s.length, sum= 0, i= 0, L= s.length, next, val,
        R={
            M: 1000, D: 500, C: 100, L: 50, X: 10, V: 5, I: 1
        };
        while(i< L){
            val= s.charAt(i++);
            if(!R[val]) return NaN;
            val= R[val];
            next= R[(s.charAt(i) || 'N')] || 0;
            if(next> val) val*= -1;
            sum+= val;
        }
        return sum
    }
    var U= document.getElementById('list'), Li= U.childNodes, 
    L= Li.length, A= [];
    for(var i= 0; i<L; i++){
        if(Li[i].id) A.push(Li[i]);
    }
    A.sort(function(a, b){
        return fromRoman(a.id)- fromRoman(b.id)
    });
    while(A.length) U.appendChild(A.shift());
    return U;
}
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('list').onclick=sortRomanIds;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Small Page</h1>
<ul id="list">
  <li id="I">one</li>
  <li id="II">two</li>
  <li id="III">three</li>
  <li id="IV">four</li>
  <li id="IX">nine</li>
  <li id="V">five</li>
  <li id="VI">six</li>
  <li id="VII">seven</li>
</ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, XSLT will only sort on a value that you can specify as text or number (...data-type="text|number"...). You might be able to add another attribute that is the number value of the roman numeral id (e.g. ...id="II" data-decimal="2"...), then sort on that with data-type number.

Answer (score 0):

Use sortContent JQuery plugin , it is very powreful plugin for sorting :

after extending Number object by `fromRomaon` and `toRoman` functions, Use the plugin as following :

```
$('#list').sortContent({asc:true,helperxp:myHelper})
```

Note: helperxp option has `getter` & `setter`, you should implement getter to get the value of attr ID , and setter to set the new value of attr ID since you sort according that attr.

```
var myHelper={
   get:function(e){
    return Number.fromRoman(e.attr('id'))+'';
   },
   set:function(e,newVal){
       $(e).attr('id',(parseInt(newVal)).toRoman());
   }

}
```

**DEMO**:

http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/6RtVc/4/